# The default django admin causes lot of problems

Tags: django

As I'm new to Django so I'm going to ask a stupid  question on how to use Django features of session , cookies without using default django admin , I mean deleting it and creating everything new.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: Delete `django.contrib.admin` from `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings?

Comment: I have created a new user model and I want to do form validation with data from database how can I do this.? Can it be possible using Auth?

Answer (score 0):

Well in Django the admin panel is very customizable you can just read the documents about how to customize your Admin panel. you just need to import CustomUsers in the models
[here is the link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/). And admin panel of Django is great so it is always recommendable but if you still don't want it then just remove in from the main URL.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',include('mainprocess.urls')),
```

]

just remove the admin path and add your self-made path.

Comment: I want to remove unnecessary stuffs like authorization users and groups and also , it's a bit complicated to be used by a client. Any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: use random function of python to create session token. make it in such a way that the user can only login if the session token in 0 and password matcher with the original password. you can use Django Hashers to Hash the password

Answer (score 0):

Django admin is just a tool which is not required for any other features by any mean.
So you just need to search about topics you said you want to have in youtube and find videos about it and learn!
my suggestion is to not learn anything related to html and templates and forms in django because it will not be used in your job in company in feature and focusing on creating API and Authentication and writing models on django